# Fixed serialized (json) response for a specific route scope

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is there any way to force the response-type for a given route?
For example: Every controller in the `/api/*` scope should always return a json-formatted response. Regardless of the request `accept-header`.

I use the `'RequestHandler'-Plugin` to serialize Data if the accept-header is set to `json` or `xml` but i always want to respond with json.

I am currently doing this:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
  if(substr($this->request->url, 0, 4) === "api/") {
    if(!$this->request->accepts('application/json')) {
      // Throw exception
    }
  }
}
```